# An interview question

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Given a linked list of **T** size , select first **2n** nodes and delete first **n** nodes from them; Then do it for the next 2n nodes and so on...

For example-
Let's consider a linked list of size **7**:

```
  `1->2->3->4->5->6->7`
```

If **n = 2**, the desired output is :

```
  `1->2->5->6->7`
```

I didn't understand what this problem is actually indicating.Could somebody help me to understand the problem ?

**EDIT :** Adding C and C++ tags so  that this may reach to more eye balls, and of-course those are only two languages allowed in the interview itself.

Comment: Your problem statement and example contradict each other.

Comment: @Alok :Yes but I copied exactly what it is presented to me.

Comment: The "first" seems like it should be "last", i.e. "select 2n first nodes and delete *last* n nodes from them".

Comment: @nthgreek: well, you should have asked for a clarification then.  The question, as it stands, doesn't make any sense.  As others have said, you probably mean "last", not "first".

Comment: @nthrgeek: it would be helpful to see the expected output of one more iteration. Should that be `1->2->7` ?

Comment: ... and even then, with that description I would have removed 7 also (belongs to the second half of the second block, that happens to be incomplete). In an interview, understanding of the problem at hand is one of the things I would test. And that does not mean understanding from the first exposition of the problem, but rather the fact that _before_ doing any work they ask as many questions as required to get all requirements. Else you will end-up coding solutions to the wrong problem.

Comment: Normally interviewers aren't looking for the answer but the way you approach the answer. And if you don't understand the question initially, it is always a good idea to ask for a clarification then to make wild guesses. This actually portrays a better image of you. You should've asked for clarification on this one from the interviewer.

Comment: If that is exactly what was presented to you, the interviewer may have been checking how you would handle ambiguous or internally inconsistent instructions. That would be rough, but certainly would give them a lot of info about candidates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That actually looks like it should say:

> Given a linked list of T size , select first 2n nodes and delete **last** n nodes from them; Then do it for the next 2n nodes and so on...

or:

> Given a linked list of T size , select first 2n nodes and **keep** first n nodes from them; Then do it for the next 2n nodes and so on...

That would mean select 1,2,3,4 then delete 3,4 (or keep 1,2 which is the same thing). Then select 5,6,7,8, not possible so stop.

Comment: Yes it seems there is a flaw in the statement.The last should be first :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's even simpler than @paxdiablo indicates ...

```
do
  take n
  skip n
until you run out of elements to take or skip
```